# how to save user credentials in local storage so user does not have to login again and again in flutter using the webview_flutter version 4.2.4

Tags: flutter, http, local-storage, flutter-dependencies, webview-flutter

currently I am loading a webpage that has a registration form using webview_flutter 4.2.4 , I want to store the credentials. so that when the user opens the app he doesn't need to login again. Is this possible that I can get session variable and store them in local storage or some other mechanism to serve my purpose. I am really new to flutter WebView